# How can we calculate the value based on the ratio that calculated from the number of previous column by SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let me explain more:
My data

```
Cus_name    Group    Cus_received      Bonus
   X          A          1000           16,5   
   Y          A          2000           46,5   
   Z          A          3000           76,5
```

Bonus = (Cus_received - 450$) * 0,03
-- 450, 0,03 are constant in our formula --

The column Bonus was calculated wrong in this case. If group A only 1 customer, the result is right. But because 3 customers in group A, the result should be like

```
X:Y:Z = 1000:2000:3000= 1:2:3
Sum= 1000+2000+3000=6000.
Sum(bonus)= (6000 - 450) * 0,03 = 166,5
then Bonus(X) = 166,5 * 1  / (1+2+3) = 27,5
Bonus(Y) = 166,5 * 2 / (1+2+3) = 55
Bonus (Z)= 166,5 * 3 / (1+2+3) = 83,25
```

---

Like I described If group A only 1 customer, the result is right. But if n customers > 1 in the same group, then The bonus column needs to be calculated based on sum(cus_received) and then divide by the ratio. Please, help me solve that how to build this process by SQL? Thank you!

Comment: I don't get the logic you are describing. Please show us the result you want.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Big Query. I removed these conflicting tags, please tag only one database.

Comment: How is the $20 calculated?

Comment: I did change my data and description to make clear my problem, thank you guys for explore more my problem!

Comment: where $450 comes from?

Comment: 450$ is a constant from our formula

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate an overall result with analytic function `SUM` for all the rows, apply your formula to that sum and calculate a ratio by dividing current value ov `A` to that sum. Because you do not provide any "formula to calculate commission", I've used fixed percent.

```sql
with a as (
  select 1 as n, 1000 as A from dual union all
  select 2 as n, 2000 as A from dual union all
  select 3 as n, 3000 as A from dual
)
select
  n,
  a,
  ( a / sum(a) over() )
    * ( 0.15 * sum(a) over() /*15% comm rate*/) as b
from a
```

Comment: Thanks, astentx, but I change my data and description to clear my problem more. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @DeeJohn I've confused by the change of DBMS tag from Oracle to BigQuery, but Mikhail Berlyant's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select *, 
  0.03 * Cus_received * (1 - 450 / (sum(Cus_received) over(partition by `group`))) Bonus
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I assume that the commission rate is 0.33333333% -- which would be a $20 commission on $6000, then you can just calculate it in each row:

```
select t.*, a * (20.0 / 6000) as b
from t;
```

If you have $20 that you want to spread over the three rows, then use window functions to calculate the ratios:

```
select t.*,
       (20 * a / sum(a) over ()) as b
from t;
```

Comment: thank you, Gordon, but I change my data and description to clear my problem more. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @DeeJohn . . . It is rude to change a question after it has been answered in a such a way that invalidates questions.  It attracts downvotes.  The right thing to do is to ask another question.